# Change the color and size scroll bar only using css / without -webkit?

Tags: css, colors, size, scrollbar

How can I change the color and size scroll bar only using css and without -webkit (because it is not supported by google chrome) ?

(I have seen a similar post, but it did not helped me in this case.)

This is my code :

```
<div class="wrapper">
...
</div>

html,body{
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
overflow-x: scroll;
height: 100%;
}

body {
overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
max-width: 110px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #3691b0;
height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: it's hard and there is no cross-browser way; check at https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar

Comment: ok thank you for this information